# How to properly create a raw transaction and sign it using web3 in browser

Tags: web3js, private-key, raw-transaction, signature

I want to create and sign a transaction in browser using web3. In order to create a raw transaction, I think I have to do something like this (hopefully you can fill the gaps of my knowledge)

```
var pk = '0x6ba33b3f7997c2bf63d82f3baa1a8069014a59fa1f554af3266aa85afee9d0a9';

pk = new Buffer(pk,'hex');

var address = '0xFb4d271F3056aAF8Bcf8aeB00b5cb4B6C02c7368';

var myContractsAddress = '0x0cb4edc28d17c43a75797bf5effc141fd5da8715';

var rawTx = {

nonce: web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(acct1)),

to: myContractsAddress,

gasPrice: web3.toHex(20000000000),

gasLimit: web3.toHex(200000),

value: ***Here I am not sure, am I supposed to encode my list of variables? and do I encode everything to hex, or just integers? And how would that list look like?***

data: *This field is irrelevant for now, and just for documentationpurpose, right?*
}
```

This should give me my raw transaction (the part about the datafield I unfortunately don't know and would love to get help with!

Lets say my raw transaction is valid and correct at this point, I would have to sign it with the private key now. The solution I've seen used a node.js library called **ethereumjs-tx**. Is there a solution with web3 only, or do I have to port this library somehow into my browser?

Comment: `ethereumjs-tx` doesn't need to be "ported" to the browser, since it already works fine there. Do you have the ABI for your contract? `value` is the amount of ether you're sending (perhaps 0 if you're just calling a contract function). `data` is what tells the contract what function you're calling (via a hash called a "function selector") and with what parameters (ABI-encoded). If you have the ABI, web3.js can compute the `data` field for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do have the contracts abi. 
So for value I'd use **web3.toHex(0)**
If you don't mind, please share with me an example of how to fill the data-field. lets assume the abi is stored under var abi = ...;

Comment: Then the two answers here should work for you.

Comment: I've updated my reply again, misstyped it a little

Comment: I think my answer already shows how to fill in the data field.

Comment: oh yeah, it does. I had to refresh, my bad and thanks a lot for the fast response <3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Below is working code that calls "increment" on https://programtheblockchain.com/dapps/counter. (More info about that sample here: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/.)

It uses `web3.js` and `ethereumjs-tx`:

```
<!-- from https://github.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds/raw/master/dist/ethereumjs-tx/ethereumjs-tx-1.3.3.min.js -->
<script src="ethereumjs-tx-1.3.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var address = "0xf15090c01bec877a122b567e5552504e5fd22b79";
  var abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getCount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"increment","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_count","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}];

  var account = "<REDACTED ACCOUNT ADDRESS>";
  var privateKey = "<REDACTED PRIVATE KEY WITHOUT 0x PREFIX>";

  var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    "https://ropsten.infura.io/<REDACTED API KEY"));

  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account, function (err, nonce) {
    var data = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address).increment.getData();

    var tx = new ethereumjs.Tx({
      nonce: nonce,
      gasPrice: web3.toHex(web3.toWei('20', 'gwei')),
      gasLimit: 100000,
      to: address,
      value: 0,
      data: data,
    });
    tx.sign(ethereumjs.Buffer.Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex'));

    var raw = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(raw, function (err, transactionHash) {
      console.log(transactionHash);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: okay, I unfortunately do have to bother you again... The increment function doesn't expect any params. What if it would want (string, uint256) i.E. 
Because I can't just change 

var data = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address).increment(string,uint256).getData();

Comment: The parameters get passed to `getData`: `...increment.getData("foo", 32);`

Comment: Okay, fully figured it out now, you're my hero. Can I thank you somehow?

Comment: Happy to help! Promote https://programtheblockchain.com to your Ethereum developer friends. :-)

Comment: I wish I had any developerfriends haha. link me your steamid, I can gift you something there if you want (if you even use steam)

Comment: I don't use steam. :-)

Comment: too bad. but I guess its better that way. thats why I'm asking you and not the other way around :D

Answer (score 18):

Using Web3.js 1.0.0

```
encoded = contractInstance.methods.myMethod(params).encodeABI()

var tx = {
    to : myContractAddress,
    data : encoded
}

web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey).then(signed => {
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction).on('receipt', console.log)
});
```

Comment: How can I access return values from `myMethod` ?

Comment: Seems like the raw transaction is missing some pieces, not sure if they're necessary -- does this actually work?  Does it just infer the `nonce`, `gasPrice`, `gasLimit`, etc?

Comment: @ohsully Mostly you can infer those params when using web3 and built in accounts/wallet. Occasionally operational params are atypical, which is when you need to manually set them.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this, my specific scenario is that I was trying to build a raw transaction and then sign it with an account that isn't stored in web3.  If you aren't using web3 to sign, then your `tx` object also needs to include `nonce`, `gasPrice`, `gasLimit`, `value`, and `chainId`.  These would normally be inferred by web3, but if you want to keep keys elsewhere and sign using something like `eth-lightwallet`, that's what your `tx` object needs to have set.

Comment: where do you get your privateKey when you only have a keystore file

Answer (score 0):

I was lost in this mystery for some time and end up writing a package to solve this. It is [web3js-raw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3js-raw) which is a simple wrapper around web3.js. Fully functioning sample using this could found [here](https://github.com/fidenz-chim/fundsplitter_web3jsraw.git).

You could use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to package everything into a single .js file and run on browser. Sample above explains how to use browserify as well.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I'm curious what's different/better about your library or whether it just does the same sort of thing under the hood as the code in my answer.

Comment: @smarx Surely I'm not doing anything fundamentally different. All I have done is wrapping web3.js in a manner which is easy to use. There are so many moving parts/permutations of use (for instance having variables or not, sending ether with function call or not, involvement of MetaMast under the hood, etc) when you are trying to send a transaction. So my approach is to use sendRawTransaction (which seems to be one of the underlying helper function in  web3.js) for all possible cases from deploying a contract to invoke a function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I hope, though, that cases where a user has to turn over their private keys to JavaScript in the browser are rare. :-)

Comment: I could see the convenience of not dealing with private keys for both average users and even for developers. But if DApps ever need to take off, and get into main stream, average users should have easy ways to manage their private keys. Do you think MetaMask would be the best way forward for handling private keys?  Personally I feel like it is too much to ask from an average user to install MetaMask. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think MetaMask (or something like it) is definitely the way to go. If users are pasting their private keys into web pages, I think cryptocurrency will surely die a quick death when everyone gets their money stolen. :-) But it's early days.

Comment: Agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better and simple way to sign and execute the smart contract function. Here your function is addBonus.

First of all we'll create the smart contract instance:

```
 const createInstance = () => {
  const bscProvider = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(config.get('bscRpcURL')),
  );
  const web3BSC = new Web3(bscProvider);
  const transactionContractInstance = new web3BSC.eth.Contract(
    transactionSmartContractABI,
    transactionSmartContractAddress,
  );
  return { web3BSC, transactionContractInstance };
};
```

Now we'll create a new function to sign and execute out addBonus Function

```
const updateSmartContract = async (//parameters you need) => {
     try {
    const contractInstance = createInstance();
// need to calculate gas fees for the addBonus
    const gasFees =
      await contractInstance.transactionContractInstance.methods
        .addBonus(
         // all the parameters
        )
        .estimateGas({ from: publicAddress_of_your_desired_wallet });
   const tx = {
      // this is the address responsible for this transaction
      from: chainpalsPlatformAddress,
      // target address, this could be a smart contract address
      to: transactionSmartContractAddress,
      // gas fees for the transaction
      gas: gasFees,
      // this encodes the ABI of the method and the arguments
      data: await contractInstance.transactionContractInstance.methods
        .addBonus(
       // all the parameters
        )
        .encodeABI(),
    };
  // sign the transaction with a private key. It'll return messageHash, v, r, s, rawTransaction, transactionHash
    const signPromise =
       await contractInstance.web3BSC.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
        tx,
        config.get('WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY'),
      );
    // the rawTransaction here is already serialized so you don't need to serialize it again
    // Send the signed txn
    const sendTxn =
      await contractInstance.web3BSC.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        signPromise.rawTransaction,
      );
    return Promise.resolve(sendTxn);
} catch(error) {
  throw error;
}
    }
```

Happy coding :)