# Web3 - how to send transaction with some data and include Ether at the same time?

Tags: web3js, transactions, ether, payable

Using `web3` `0.20.3`

I want to call function and send some Etherium at the same time.

#### JavaScript

```
Contract = web3.eth.contract(ABI);

Instance = Contract.at('0x162b74ea16da6ae9d7f7b349eaeab2fcadf4e835');

Instance.setData("name", "url", function(err, result) {
  console.log(err, result);
});
```

#### Solidity

```
  function setData(string name, string imageUrl) public payable {
    accounts[msg.sender].name = name;
    accounts[msg.sender].imageUrl = imageUrl;
    accounts[msg.sender].bid = accounts[msg.sender].bid + msg.value;
    emit Bid(msg.sender, accounts[msg.sender].bid);
  }

  function() public payable { // fallback function
    accounts[msg.sender].bid = accounts[msg.sender].bid + msg.value;
    emit Bid(msg.sender, accounts[msg.sender].bid);
  }
```

---

- I know how to send Ether: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Sending-ether
- I know how to call function.
- How do I call function and send Ether at the same time using simple syntax?

Ideally something like that:

`Instance.setData("url", "name", {value: "1000000000000000000"}, function(err, result) {
  console.log(err, result);
});`

*(note adding extra `value` parameter)*

More involved syntax I've observed in the wild, but they involve manually creating the whole transaction. I just want to add sending Ether to something that I have.

- [How to properly create a raw transaction and sign it using web3 in browser](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36358/how-to-properly-create-a-raw-transaction-and-sign-it-using-web3-in-browser?rq=1)
- https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction

Comment: Did you check your code? It looks fine. You might want to add `from: web3.eth.accounts[0]` to the object you put the `value` in to make sure web3 will try to send from the 'current' account.

Comment: Rubber duck debugging. It works. Here is a great example: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#example-51

```myContractInstance.myStateChangingMethod('someParam1', 23, {value: 200, gas: 2000});``` Can I have my time back? How do we mark the question as pointless, resolved, it was always working, maybe I was so tired and forgot to save the file or reload the page...

Comment: Haha I know this kind of issue, don't worry about it.