# Interact with a contract using Web3 Wallet

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, blockchain

I am trying to interact with a contract without a provider as Metamask/Mist. I know that web3 has an option to create a new Wallet and I have been seeing code examples about that but all of them sending a normal transaction of ethers and I am a bit confused how to use it when I want to interact with a function in the contract.

One example is in [pet-shop-tutorial](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop). When you want to adopt a pet, you send a transaction from the .js file calling the `adopt` function with the account:

```
App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    adoptionInstance = instance;
    // Execute adopt as a transaction by sending account
    return adoptionInstance.adopt(petId, {from: account});
  })
```

I am trying to do that using a web3 provider with the private key because I dont want to confirm the tx through Metamask. How could I do it? is there any example of that? It will be very helpful if someone could apply it in this example.

Comment: Maybe this could be of help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/36363/44533 :)