# How to update value on ethereum blockchain without metamask?

Tags: ether, metamask, dapps

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract UniToken{
    string value="Hello";

    function set(string x) public {
        value = x;
    }
    function get() public view returns (string) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

.

```
contract.methods.set(newValue)
.send({ from: "My Ether Address"
})
```

In the above code, i am using my ether address but its responding with error

**"Returned error: unknown account"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does not supply "Account" to send the message from.

You have to options :

Use web3.eth.account[N] (E.g.: eth.accounts[0]) to send transaction.

```
contract.methods.set(newValue)
.send({ from: web3.eth.account[0]
})
```

Or, you need to sign the transaction with your private key.

Example : [How to properly create a raw transaction and sign it using web3 in browser](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36358/how-to-properly-create-a-raw-transaction-and-sign-it-using-web3-in-browser?rq=1)