# Calling payable state changing function on client side with metamask in ethereum infura testnet

Tags: web3js, transactions, infura, ganache, react

I can't seem to find an answer for my problem, or it's either impossible and I'm missing something, or it's trivial and I'm missing something.

I have this function on client side:

```
const bet = web3.utils.toWei(bet.toString(), 'ether')
let gasEstimated = 135335 //default

Contract.methods.joinGame(id).estimateGas({ from: account, value: bet }).then(function (gasAmount) {
    gasEstimated = gasAmount
})

Contract.methods.joinGame(id).send({ from: account, gas: gasEstimated, value: bet }).then((result, error) => {
    if (error) return console.log('ERROR_PAYING', error)
})
```

It gives me an `eth_sendTrasaction` does not exist error. 
My final objective would be for the client to pay with metamask once the `joingame` function is called.

Disclaimer: I also tried with `web3.eth.sendTransaction`

It works with ganache-cli

Answer (score 1):

Infura doesn't support underlying JSON-RPC method for `eth_sendTransaction`. Infura only blocks methods that do not make sense for Infura, such as those that require Infura to store private keys. `web3.eth.sendTransaction` invokes the `eth_sendTransaction` method (which requires the server to hold keys), and therefore is unsupported by Infura (but is supported by `ganache-cli`).

You need to use the web3 method that instead invokes `eth_sendRawTransaction`, so that the transaction signing happens locally. This, of course, would require you to generate the raw transaction and sign it locally prior to calling `eth_sendRawTransaction`.

[Here is a good example of what it should look like](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36358/how-to-properly-create-a-raw-transaction-and-sign-it-using-web3-in-browser).

Comment: So there is no way to use infura and request client payments via metamask? If they want to make a transaction they would need to give me their wallet PK?

Comment: No, this is possible (and is how MM does it). You need to have them _locally_ create the transaction and then send the raw transaction in two steps (as opposed to simply calling `send` in a single step). So instead of your `send` function, you would build the transaction _and then_ send it. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Having this in mind: ````var tx = new ethereumjs.Tx({
      nonce: nonce,
      gasPrice: web3.toHex(web3.toWei('20', 'gwei')),
      gasLimit: 100000,
      to: address,
      value: 0,
      data: data,
    });
    tx.sign(ethereumjs.Buffer.Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex'));

    var raw = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(raw, function (err, transactionHash) {
      console.log(transactionHash);
    });````  what should be the PK field on my code in order to sign the raw transaction? Or I should just ignore the tx.sign part?