# Can I use a truffle-contract instance in the data field of web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction?

Tags: web3js, truffle-contract

I use `truffle-contract` for contract abstraction.

```
const myContract = TruffleContract(MyContractArtifact);

myContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
```

I'm using Infura as the web3 provider so need to sign transactions before sending them. If I want to use contract functions in the `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction` `data` field, can this be done with the `myContract` instance? I understand it can be done with `web3.eth.Contract` based on [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/52784/47006) answer, so if it is actually possible, is it more or less the same technique, or what would I need to do?

Edit* I have given up on truffle-contract and using `web3.eth.Contract.methods.myMethod.encodeABI()`

Edi2* Changed title as I was wrong to say `sendTransaction()` - the method I require is `sendSignedTransaction()`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to create a "raw" to contract?

Comment: Sorry Ismael I'm not sure what that is. Basically, if truffle-contract has the equivalent of web3.eth.Contracts.method.encodeABI() (which is what you might have meant.)  I have actually given up on truffle-contract and moved to the web3 contract abstraction, and have an offline signing solution in place that uses web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction